# MongoDB: Find and Update or Create from stream of subscription with large simultaneous data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I would like to find a solution to my problem: I have a subscription from external service that send a lot of information that I need to save on mongoDB and get the stored in a dashboard. Before to insert them I need to find if exist and update instead create.
This is my code:

```
await ProjectModel.findOne( { address } ).then( project => {
   if( project ) {
        project.tasked?.push( task )
        const index = ( project.owners as TypeOwners ).findIndex( ( p ) => p.owner === task.owner ) 
        if( index >= 0 && project.owners ) {
            project.owners[index].amount++
            project.owners[index].tasks.push( task.address )
            project.markModified('owners');
        } else {
            project.owners?.push( {
                tasks: [ task.address ],
                amount: 1,
                owner: task?.owner
            } )
        }
        project?.save()
        console.log( `updated: ${address}` )
   } else {
        ProjectModel.create( {
            cm_address: cm_address,
            platform: platform,
            project_symbol: symbol,
            project_collection:name,
            creator: creators as Creator[],
            description: description,
            tasked: [ tasked ],
            owners: [ {
                tasks: [ task.address ],
                amount: 1,
                owner: task?.owner
            }]
       })
       console.log( `created: ${address}` )
   }
})
```

The problem is some time the information received are simultaneous and don't give the time to mongodb to check if exist and duplicate the record (instead of update) and some time I receive this error:

`VersionError: No matching document found for id "XXXXXXXX" version 0 modifiedPaths ....`

Someone have a solution for this situation? Thank you :slight_smile:

Comment: You are not using `await` on your creates and updates. This means it could move on to the next document before the current one is complete, which may be a source of your error.

Comment: You could add a unique key to that field. That way, the second one will get an error and you can handle it in the way you prefer.